# How do you translate the phrase 'complete sentence'?

Tags: translation

I can't find anything online. Would it be 全句子？
I'm also interested to know how to say 'sentence fragment'.

Comment: online：for "complete sentence"  **Line Dict**   has 62 usage results: 完整的句子,  **ICIBA** : ３ usage examples:完全句,完整的句子,完整的句子, **ichacha**  :a complete sentence    完整的句子,  **google translate** :a complete sentence 一个完整的句子, **jukuu**  has 29 samples, with 1-8 relevant, 7 have 完整的句子,one has 完全句（尤指有几个分句者）, for **"sentence fragment"**  jukuu has 句子片段, also note a complex sentence 复句 consists of clauses **分句** ， **全句**  means "the whole sentence"  see jukuu

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **complete sentence**
>
> 完全句
>   《懶蟲簡明英漢詞典》

or

> **full sentence**
>
> 完全句
>   《懶蟲簡明英漢詞典》
>
> 完整句子
>   《21世紀英漢漢英雙向詞典》

and

> **sentence fragment**
>
> 句子片段
>   《21世紀雙語科技詞典》

We usually use a shorter term for "complete sentence", like 全句 or 整句.

Answer (score 3):

'complete sentence' is translated as  '完整句子' in Chinese

"A complete sentence" = "一句完整的句子"

> http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/8449/
>
> 完整
>
> wan2 zheng3   (pinyin)
>
> jyun4 zing2   (jyutping)
>
> **complete**; intact; whole

Answer (score 1):

'sentence fragment' is not really a concept in Chinese I think. But then, define 'sentence', Western grammar has no solid definition.

句 is a character formed from 口 and 勹。 勹 is perhaps an old version of 包. That fits nicely with 'wrap your lips around this = say this' 句子 would then be 'something you say' in Chinese.

sentence fragment: 不完整的句子

Answer (score 0):

It means, 完整的句子
learn more about Chinese here：
[Chinese learning](http://www.hanbridgemandarin.com/course/demo/hsk_grammar)